# CSS variables defaults: set if not already set

Tags: css, css-variables

My Web Component uses CSS variables.

These variables need default values.

They are used in many files, so I want to provide the defaults *once, and only once*.

This first attempt makes the text black. Why?

What is the correct way to provide the defaults once?

```css
.a {
  --my-variable: red;
}

.b {
  --my-variable: var(--my-variable, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <span style="color: var(--my-variable);">text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My theory is `--my-variable` is that not in inline style scope

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This first attempt makes the text black. Why?

Because this `--my-variable: var(--my-variable, blue);` is invalid as you are trying to express the same variable with itself which is not allowed so the browser will simply ignore it. Then later when using `color: var(--my-variable);` the color will fallback to the `initial` value which is black.

The correct way is to simply define the variable on an upper level and it will get inherited by all the element (like the solution provided by @kornieff)

---

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#cycles):

> Custom properties are left almost entirely unevaluated, except that they allow and evaluate the var() function in their value. **This can create cyclic dependencies** where a custom property uses a var() **referring to itself**, or two or more custom properties each attempt to refer to each other.
>
> For each element, create a directed dependency graph, containing nodes for each custom property. If the value of a custom property prop contains a var() function referring to the property var (including in the fallback argument of var()), add an edge between prop and the var. Edges are possible from a custom property to itself. **If there is a cycle in the dependency graph**, *all the custom properties in the cycle must compute to their initial value* (which is a guaranteed-invalid value).

Comment: Excellent answer. My question lacked one detail: The CSS is inside of a Shadow DOM. I don't have access to an upper level. Do you have a suggestion for this scenario?

Comment: @mikabytes you can consider the `:host` element, it should be an upper level in your case

Comment: That would break inheritance, right? But agree it would be good enough as long as the consumer target my component directly.

Comment: @mikabytes it may affect inheritance but only inside your component so it will depend on how your component is built and how you are using CSS variables inside.

Comment: Only variables set directly on my component will make it into my component, as demonstrated here https://gist.github.com/mikabytes/83779917befa6e97f541a93305aa46f3 Unfortunately, means there is no good way for setting web component variable defaults without also breaking inheritance.

Answer (score 20):

To complement the previous answers, there might be a case where you don't want to declare your variables in the global `:root` scope. For example, when you're creating a re-usable component, you want to declare its styles locally, without depending on the global project styles. Especially if you're building a library for other developers.

In that case, the solution is to expose one variable name to the "outer world", and use a different variable name inside of the component. The component container should just map the optional external variable to the inner variable, and set its default value:

```css
.my-component-container {
  /* map optional "external" variables to required "internal" variables */
  --my-variable-inner: var(--my-variable, blue);
}

.my-component-container .my-nested-element {
  color: var(--my-variable-inner);
}

.my-component-container .my-other-nested-element {
  border-color: var(--my-variable-inner);
}
```

This way you can ensure that `--my-variable-inner` is always defined in the component, and make it optional for the external consumers to define `--my-variable`.

The downside is that you need to remember two variable names instead of one. But here you can think of some project-wide convention, e.g. add `--inner` or some other suffix to each variable like that.

Comment: This is relevant. Because this allows default value for `--my-variable-inner`, with global backing. I just wish I could do it without having to introduce a new variable.

Answer (score 14):

Declare default values in `:root`, then override in selectors.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: red;
}

* {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  --primary-color: green;
}

p {
  --primary-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>HI!</div>
&hellip;
<p>Bye!</p>
```